# How to power by an expression in LabVIEW

Tags: labview

I just started today to learn LabVIEW to complete a specific assignment. I need to write the equation `y= (1+ r/n)^(nt+1)` but do not know how to write `(nt+1)` as an index. Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it in LabVIEW, but note there is no error checking, or input checking.

[image]

Comment: Sir, thanks a lot for your suggestion. Finally, I could do it. Thanks again.